# Rotating images causes distortion on Qt

Tags: c++, qt, image-rotation, rounding-error

I'm facing some problems rotating an image in Qt.  Each time I rotate my image with [QPainter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QPainter.html) it becomes more and more distorted.  This is the initial image:

[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/838/ship1.png/]

After some iterations it becomes:

[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/11/ship2e.png/]

This is my code:

```
void Ship::Move(int x, int y)
{
    QPixmap rotatePixmap(shipPixels.size());
    rotatePixmap.fill(Qt::transparent);

    QTransform transform;
    transform.translate(
            rotatePixmap.size().width() / 2,
            rotatePixmap.size().height() / 2
    );

    transform.rotate(degree);
    transform.translate(
            - rotatePixmap.size().width() / 2, 
            - rotatePixmap.size().height() / 2
    );

    QPainter p(&rotatePixmap);
    p.setRenderHints(
            QPainter::Antialiasing | QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform,
            true
    );

    p.setTransform(transform);
    p.drawPixmap(0, 0, shipPixels);
    p.end();

    shipPixels = rotatePixmap;
    this->setPixmap(shipPixels);
    this->move(QPoint(x, y));
    degree = 0;
}
```

For me Qt preserves image quality. The behavior is totally strange. Is there a reason?

Comment: You need to calculate the new rotation bitmap fresh each time. You are accumulating round off errors.

Comment: Yeah, if you leave shipPixels untouched between frames and instead use it as your anchor, you should be good to go.

Comment: The effect you're seeing is unavoidable because rotation by any amount other than 90 degree increments is a lossy operation. The losses add up. It has nothing to do with Qt.

Comment: @MarkRansom good point, though theory and practice don't always mesh -- I'm sure there are several libraries out there that would blur or otherwise distort an image at 90 degree increments! :-/

Answer (score 1):

Based on answers new code is this. Other users that find themselves with same problem can get this code:

```
void Ship::Move(int x, int y)
{
    QPixmap sourceImage(shipPixels);

    QPixmap rotatePixmap(sourceImage.size());
    rotatePixmap.fill(Qt::transparent);

    QTransform transform;
    transform.translate(sourceImage.size().width() / 2, sourceImage.size().height() / 2);
    transform.rotate(degree);
    transform.translate(-sourceImage.size().width() / 2, -sourceImage.size().height() / 2);

    QPainter p;
    p.setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing|QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform, true);
    p.begin(&rotatePixmap);
    p.setTransform(transform);
    p.drawPixmap(0, 0, sourceImage);
    p.end();

    rotatePixmap.save("temp.png");

    this->setPixmap(rotatePixmap);
    this->move(QPoint(x, y));
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
QPainter pixmap;
pixmap.setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing|QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform,true);
```

that's what you are looking for.